# How to stop users from checking Radio Buttons android

Tags: android

So I have this buttons:

[image]

What I want is to stop users from checking or unchecking any of them. Anyway i tried with `android:enable = "false"` but it does not seems to be a solution since the buttons gets faded and that is something i do not want

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your both radio button `clickable="False"`

By xml

```
android:clickable="false"
```

by Programmatically

```
radiobuttonOne.setClickable(false);
radiobuttonTwo.setClickable(false);
```

it works for you

Answer (score 0):

You can set your drawables on `RadioButton`:

```
  <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@drawable/btn_radio"
        android:text="RadioButton" />
```

**btn_radio.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_window_focused="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_on" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_window_focused="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_off" />

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_on_pressed" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_off_pressed" />

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_on_selected" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_off_selected" />

    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_off" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_on" />
</selector>
```

Replace the `btn_radio_on` and `btn_radio_off_selected` with your own drawables.

Answer (score 0):

Do as you did before with `android:enable = "false"` but only change the disabled/enabled colour of your radio button in your `styles.xml`, add these lines to your App Theme:

```
<item name="colorControlActivated">your_color_for_activated</item>
<item name="colorControlNormal">your_color_for_normal</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

RadioButton extends CompoundButton

```
android:clickable="false"
android:enabled="false"
android:checked="true"
android:focusable="false"
```

Answer (score -1):

`android:clickable = "false"` seemed to be the answer of the question but the problem was that i was setting onClickListener on the buttons which actually calls setClickable(true). I just made it programmatically after the onClickListener. Now it works